# When validating parameters for a Rails model, can you check one param's value in relation to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my current Rails project, I have a model called "Child," with two parameters, "choc_cupcake" and "cherry_cupcake."

Each child should be allowed to have up to 5 cupcakes total, in any combination of chocolate and/or cherry cupcakes.  So far, my model validation code just allows each child to have up to 5 chocolate cupcakes AND up to 5 cherry cupcakes.

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :choc_cupcake, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 5 }
  validates :cherry_cupcake, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 5 }
end
```

Is there a way to specify that if a child chooses X chocolate cupcakes, then he/she can have no more than (5-X) cherry cupcakes?  Something like this, maybe?

```
validates :cherry_cupcake, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: (5 - :choc_cake) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :choc_cupcake, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}
  validates :cherry_cupcake, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}
  validate :no_more_than_5_total_cupcakes

  private

  def no_more_than_5_total_cupcakes
    if (choc_cupcake + cherry_cupcake) > 5
      message = "No more than 5 total cupcakes!"
      errors.add(choc_cupcake: message)
      errors.add(cherry_cupcake: message)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Now, when I try to add a Child object in the rails console, it's giving me this message: "ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation"  :(

Comment: my fault. `errors.add` can't accept two attributes at a time.